# Error Uploading File PHP with SQL filepath

Tags: php, sql, file-upload

I am trying to upload an image to a directory and post its file path along with other data into a table. Upon submit it echos Error uploading file, but i cant figure out where its getting hung up. I believe it may have to do with my result variable but I'm not sure why. Thank you for your help.

```html
<!-- Updated -->
    <?PHP
    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $hostname = "localhost:3306"; 
    $db_user = "root"; 
    $db_password = "admin"; 
    $database = "smlc"; 
    $db_table = "program";
    $db = mysqli_connect($hostname, $db_user, $db_password);
          mysqli_select_db($db, $database);
       
    $uploadDir=dirname(__FILE__)."/images/uploaded/programs/";

    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {
    $program_name = $_POST['program_name'];
    $program_description = $_POST['program_description'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['Photo']['name'];
    $tmpName = $_FILES['Photo']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['Photo']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['Photo']['type'];
    $filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;
    $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName,$filePath);
    if (!$result) {
    echo "Error uploading file";
    exit;
    }
    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    $filePath = addslashes($filePath);
    }

    $sql_program = "INSERT INTO program (program_name, program_description,filepath) 
    VALUES ('$program_name', '$program_description','$filePath')";


    mysqli_query($sql_program) or die('Error, query failed ');
    }
    ?>
```

```
<!--image_programs.php-->
  

      <?PHP
        $hostname = "localhost"; 
        $db_user = "*"; 
        $db_password = "*"; 
        $database = "smlc"; 
        $db_table = "program";
        $db = mysql_connect($hostname, $db_user, $db_password);
              mysql_select_db($database);
           
        $uploadDir = 'images/Uploaded/programs/'; 
    
        if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
        {
        $program_name = $_POST['program_name'];
        $program_description = $_POST['program_description'];
        $fileName = $_FILES['Photo']['name'];
        $tmpName = $_FILES['Photo']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['Photo']['size'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['Photo']['type'];
        $filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;
        $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName,$filePath);
        if (!$result) {
        echo "Error uploading file";
        exit;
        }
        if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
        $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
        $filePath = addslashes($filePath);
        }
    
        $sql_program = "INSERT INTO program (program_name, program_description,filepath) 
        VALUES ('$program_name', '$program_description','$filePath' )";
    
    
        mysql_query($sql_program,$db) or die('Error, query failed ');
        }
        ?>






<!-- Image Form -->

 <form name="Image" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="image_programs.php" method="POST">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <input type="File" name="Photo" size="2000000" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/x-ms-bmp, image/x-png" size="26"></td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td width="100">Program Name</td>
                    <td><input class="commentarea" name="program_name" type="text" id="program_name"></td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td width="100">Program Description</td>
                    <td><input class="commentarea" name="program_description" type="text"      id="program_description"></td>
                </tr>
                
                <br/>
                
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <INPUT type="Submit" class="button" name="Submit" value="Submit">
                    </td>
                </tr>          
   </form>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: These are the returned results:Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SMLC\includes\image_programs.php on line 10

Warning: move_uploaded_file(.../smlc/images/Uploaded/programs/pew.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\SMLC\includes\image_programs.php on line 23

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php4A35.tmp' to '.../smlc/images/Uploaded/programs/pew.jpg' in C:\xampp\htdocs\SMLC\includes\image_programs.php on line 23
Error uploading file

Comment: `mysql_select_db($database,$db);` that will fix the 1st error. `$uploadDir = 'images/Uploaded/programs/';` and your error is `Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php4A35.tmp' to '.../smlc/images/Uploaded/programs/pew.jpg'` not the same folder. Plus, seems to have 3 dots in there.

Comment: Sidenote:: On Linux, `Uploaded` is not the same as `uploaded`, should your folder be all in lowercase.

Comment: Do I need to have my image/uploaded/programs folder located inside my includes? I would prefer not to do that...

Comment: It should be uppercase. good thought though...

Comment: The way you've got your upload location setup, the script would need to reside just outside the `image` folder, one sub-folder down.

Comment: Another thing you could probably get away with in doing, is setting your upload location as a full path. I.e.: `$uploadDir = '/var/usr/public_html/images/Uploaded/programs/';`

Comment: If I move it into the right folder i get now have....Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SMLC\image_programs.php on line 38

Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SMLC\image_programs.php on line 38

Comment: Hard to say at this point why you're getting that error. Might be because you need to use `mysqli_` functions instead of `mysql_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$uploadDir=dirname(__FILE__)."/images/Uploaded/programs/";
```

and images folder should be in same folder that your current file located
Uploaded and uploaded are not same name depending on server.
So take care about your folder names too.

Comment: Still the same error...
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SMLC\image_programs.php on line 38

Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SMLC\image_programs.php on line 38

Comment: I actually already changed the folder name to lowercase for continuity... thank you though

Comment: It seems your upload problem fixed.try using this mysql_query($sql_program) instead of mysql_query($sql_program,$db)

Comment: mysqli_query($db, $sql_program); in sqli syntax the $db parameter needed to to be listed first. Thanks for your help